# Using C# to display an XML file transformed by XSLT

Tags: c#, xml, xslt

I don't know if this is possible or if I am thinking about this in the wrong way, but this is what I want to do:

I have an XML file linked to an XSLT file and I want to use C# to get the output of the transformed XML file and Response.Write() that wherever I want on the page.

I have found questions on stackoverflow about saving the transformed output to a new file etc, but I don't want to save it to a file, I just want to display it with Response.Write() anywhere on my aspx page.

Is there any way to do this in C#?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: why don't you simply set the text property of a label with the result of the transformation, instead of using Response.Write ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, save the transformed file to a MemoryStream (so in memory not the hard disk). You can then output that to a string using a filestrem reader.

Comment: You mean `MemoryStream`, not `FileStream`. As the name implies, `FileStream` writes to a **file**

Comment: I think this answer is the closest to what I want to do. The XML part of this page is only a small piece of data which I happen to need on this page only, so it seems a bit pointless to rebuild an entire page in XML just to do that. Also thank you Danial Hilgarth for mentioning MemoryStream instead of FileStream. This answer and the comments have pointed me in the right direction. I ended up finding and using the code on this site as a base for what I want to do: http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/CSharp/0540__XML/UseMemoryStreamtoholdtheXmlTransformresult.htm

Answer (score 2):

Another way of doing it is by using the XML control, it has XML and XSLT properties.

Answer (score 1):

You could save yourself the effort and simply serve up the XML to the browser. As long as the XML document references the URL of the corresponding XSLT document, the browser will render the page for you.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`HttpResponse.OutputStream`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.outputstream.aspx) as output stream to save transformed file.